# I active my wp rocket then my site in not running that showing only page is not working

Tags: wordpress

I activated my wp-rocket using cpanel then i tried my site that this showing image.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Go to cpanel/ ftp, plugins folder, delete the plugin, reload the website.

If you want to speed up your website, develop a theme from scratch, plugins make website vulnerable and bulky. Use optimized images, less in disk space and high in quality.

Comment: But I want to only this plugin so what can i do?

Comment: change theme and check if it's working, if it's working then it's your theme issue or else plugin issue.

Answer (score 2):

There are several reasons for that:

- Disable all plugins and check the response somehow cache plugin conflict with one of theme plugin
- Set permalink structure
- Clear cache of your site through the plugin
- just for cross-checking test another cache plugin

Once you check all the above points and found no luck so it must be your theme development issue than check your hooks which you have used in your theme development.